# python base64decode error between strings

Tags: python

I am currently working with a programming challenge where I need to strip out base64 text from a string, decode it and then do more fun stuff.

I have done the first bit stripping the base64 text out and saving it to flat file, I am doing a second pass over it and I'm getting a padding error.

```
print(base64.b64decode(next))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/base64.py", line 78, in b64decode
raise TypeError(msg)
TypeError: Incorrect padding
```

Now the code I wrote is extremely simple

```
o.write(str(i) + ". "+base64.b64decode(next)+"\n\r")
```

and the first 36 strings correctly decode but 37, 38 etc are not. Here are the two examples

> Line 36:
>   QVNDLChzZWxlY3QgKGNhc2UgZmllbGQoY29uY2F0KHN1YnN0cmluZyhiaW4oYXNjaWkoc3Vic3RyaW5nKHBhc3N3b3JkLDksMSkpKSw3LDEpKSxjaGFyKDQ4KSxjaGFyKDQ5KSkgd2hlbiAxIHRoZW4gc2xlZXAoMikgd2hlbiAyIHRoZW4gc2xlZXAoNCkgIGVuZCkgZnJvbSBtZW1icmVzIHdoZXJlIGlkPTEp=

decodes to 36.

```
ASC,(select (case field(concat(substring(bin(ascii(substring(password,9,1))),7,1)),char(48),char(49)) when 1 then sleep(2) when 2 then sleep(4)  end) from membres where id=1)
```

> line 37:
>   QVNDLChzZWxlY3QgKGNhc2UgZmllbGQoY29uY2F0KHN1YnN0cmluZyhiaW4oYXNjaWkoc3Vic3RyaW5nKHBhc3N3b3JkLDEwLDEpKSksMSwxKSxzdWJzdHJpbmcoYmluKGFzY2lpKHN1YnN0cmluZyhwYXNzd29yZCwxMCwxKSkpLDIsMSkpLGNvbmNhdChjaGFyKDQ4KSxjaGFyKDQ4KSksY29uY2F0KGNoYXIoNDgpLGNoYXIoNDkpKSxjb25jYXQoY2hhcig0OSksY2hhcig0OCkpLGNvbmNhdChjaGFyKDQ5KSxjaGFyKDQ5KSkpd2hlbiAxIHRoZW4gVFJVRSB3aGVuIDIgdGhlbiBzbGVlcCgyKSB3aGVuIDMgdGhlbiBzbGVlcCg0KSB3aGVuIDQgdGhlbiBzbGVlcCg2KSBlbmQpIGZyb20gbWVtYnJlcyB3aGVyZSBpZD0xKQ=

I tested string 37 in an online base64 decoder (base64decode.org) and it works

```
ASC,(select (case field(concat(substring(bin(ascii(substring(password,10,1))),1,1),substring(bin(ascii(substring(password,10,1))),2,1)),concat(char(48),char(48)),concat(char(48),char(49)),concat(char(49),char(48)),concat(char(49),char(49)))when 1 then TRUE when 2 then sleep(2) when 3 then sleep(4) when 4 then sleep(6) end) from membres where id=1)
```

Is there something obvious I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Well, the padding on

> QVNDLChzZWxlY3QgKGNhc2UgZmllbGQoY29uY2F0KHN1YnN0cmluZyhiaW4oYXNjaWkoc3Vic3RyaW5nKHBhc3N3b3JkLDEwLDEpKSksMSwxKSxzdWJzdHJpbmcoYmluKGFzY2lpKHN1YnN0cmluZyhwYXNzd29yZCwxMCwxKSkpLDIsMSkpLGNvbmNhdChjaGFyKDQ4KSxjaGFyKDQ4KSksY29uY2F0KGNoYXIoNDgpLGNoYXIoNDkpKSxjb25jYXQoY2hhcig0OSksY2hhcig0OCkpLGNvbmNhdChjaGFyKDQ5KSxjaGFyKDQ5KSkpd2hlbiAxIHRoZW4gVFJVRSB3aGVuIDIgdGhlbiBzbGVlcCgyKSB3aGVuIDMgdGhlbiBzbGVlcCg0KSB3aGVuIDQgdGhlbiBzbGVlcCg2KSBlbmQpIGZyb20gbWVtYnJlcyB3aGVyZSBpZD0xKQ=

*is* wrong, as it has length 467, which is not divisible by 4, but [Base64 encodes 3 source octets as 4 symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Examples). It's just that [some Base64 implementations don't care about padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Implementations_and_history) (apparently including the online tool you used), while other implementations (apparently including Python's) do care.

> QVNDLChzZWxlY3QgKGNhc2UgZmllbGQoY29uY2F0KHN1YnN0cmluZyhiaW4oYXNjaWkoc3Vic3RyaW5nKHBhc3N3b3JkLDEwLDEpKSksMSwxKSxzdWJzdHJpbmcoYmluKGFzY2lpKHN1YnN0cmluZyhwYXNzd29yZCwxMCwxKSkpLDIsMSkpLGNvbmNhdChjaGFyKDQ4KSxjaGFyKDQ4KSksY29uY2F0KGNoYXIoNDgpLGNoYXIoNDkpKSxjb25jYXQoY2hhcig0OSksY2hhcig0OCkpLGNvbmNhdChjaGFyKDQ5KSxjaGFyKDQ5KSkpd2hlbiAxIHRoZW4gVFJVRSB3aGVuIDIgdGhlbiBzbGVlcCgyKSB3aGVuIDMgdGhlbiBzbGVlcCg0KSB3aGVuIDQgdGhlbiBzbGVlcCg2KSBlbmQpIGZyb20gbWVtYnJlcyB3aGVyZSBpZD0xKQ=**=**

works.